# python ctypes - wrap void pointer

Tags: python, c, sdk, ctypes, word-wrap

I am wrapping a C library into Python via ctypes. At the moment I stuck on one line or more on one parameter. Here the C Code:

```
void* gVimbaHandleFake = (void*)1;
err = VmbFeatureBoolGet(gVimbaHandleFake, "GeVTLIsPresent", &isGigE );
```

The problem is this strange void pointer. In general I know what a void pointer is but this one seems to be "special". If I change the 1 in `(void*)1` the program is not working anymore (it is about finding network cameras). It is not crashing but doesnt find the cameras anymore.

I tried many different things, the last tries in Python:

```
gVimbaHandle = cast(1, c_void_p)
err = self.dll.VmbFeatureBoolGet(byref(gVimbaHandle), "GeVTLIsPresent", byref(isGigE))
```

also tried the "normal" way:

```
gVimbaHandle = c_void_p(1)
```

My program isnt crashing but it tells me that the handle is invalid ...
When I looked into the pointer with `gVimbaHandle.value` I get `1L` as output. Could this be the problem, the `L` for the long datatype?

Does anybody knows how to fix this or can explain the "special" `(void*)1` pointer in C to me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're passing the pointer by reference, but the example C code passes it by value. Use `gVimbaHandle = c_void_p(1)` and  `VmbFeatureBoolGet(gVimbaHandle, "GeVTLIsPresent", byref(isGigE))`.

Comment: Oh yeah thats right, was kind of confused with the python and C pointer combination stuff and didnt saw this ... thank you very much. Fixed it for me. If u post it as an answer I will mark it as solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution/answer is:

```
gVimbaHandle = c_void_p(1)
err = self.dll.VmbFeatureBoolGet(gVimbaHandle, "GeVTLIsPresent", byref(isGigE))
```

thanks @eryksun